# How to access SonarQube with Kubernetes Proxy?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, sonarqube

I want to deploy SonarQube to a Kubernetes cluster. The SonarQube webapp should only be accessible via Kubernetes proxy.
When I try to access the frontend with the address:

> http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/sonar/services/sonar:80/proxy/sonar/

I see the sonarqube loading screen. But the webapp tries to access the api  with a GET request to the address

> http://localhost:8001/sonar/api/l10n/index?locale=de-DE

which is, of course, not accessible.

Is there a way to set the server base adress?

My current deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonarqube
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: sonarqube
      labels:
        name: sonarqube
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: sonarqube:latest
          args:
            - -Dsonar.web.context=/sonar
          name: sonarqube
          env:
            - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD
              value: sonar
            - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL
              value: jdbc:postgresql://sonar-postgres:5432/sonar
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
              name: sonarqube
```

Edit: the webapp loads the styling and favicon correctly.

My service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: sonar
  name: sonar
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
      name: sonarport
  selector:
    name: sonarqube
```

Comment: Can you please post the service definition for the sonarqube deployment?

Comment: Sure here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes proxy is not the best way to access the SonarQube web app inside a cluster.

You can set a base URL in the `sonar.core.serverBaseURL` property in your `sonar.properties` file on the server, but I am not sure if it will help you . Anyway, it is an unstable configuration and it will break in many cases -  e.g., access from another host.

I highly recommend you to use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and some authentication if you want additional protection (try to check [External Authentication](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth) for Nginx Ingress). Also, you can use [Port Forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) on your local machine.